# Published properties are not displayed in Delphi web service wsdl

Tags: delphi, wsdl

The class `TMyClass` from my interface file is derived from its parent class `TMyRemotable`, which in turn is derived from `TRemotable`.

The problem with the generated WSDL is that the published properties of `TMyClass` are not displayed in the `<complex>` type.

Consider the code snippets below:

Sample.pas

```pascal
TMyRemotable = class(TRemotable)
public
  class function NewInstance: TObject; override;
  destructor Destroy; override;
end;
```

UserIntf.pas  //Interface file

```pascal
TMyClass = class(TMyRemotable)
private
  FUserName: string;
  FpassWord: string;  
published
  property UserName: string read FUserName write FUserName;
  property Password: string read FpassWord write FpassWord;
end;
```

We get this output:

```xml
<types>
  <xs:schema xmlns="urn:UserIntf" targetNamespace="urn:UserIntf">
    <xs:complexType name="TMyClass">
      <xs:sequence/>
    </xs:complexType>
```

Expected output:

```xml
<types>
  <xs:schema xmlns="urn:UserIntf" targetNamespace="urn:UserIntf">
    <xs:complexType name="TMyClass">
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="UserName" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="PassWord" type="xs:string"/>
      </xs:sequence>
```

Kindly guide me to how to include the published properties in the generated WSDL file.

Answer (score 2):

If you want your properties to appear as element nodes or attributes in the corresponding SOAP encoding of the type, you need to use a bit of a different declaration for them. They actually need to be declared as indexed properties, like this:

```
published
  property Text: WideString index IS_TEXT read FText write FText;
```

You can read more about this in Embarcadero's official documentation:

[Using Remotable Objects](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Using_Remotable_Objects)